# Converting ASCII strings into numbers

Tags: coding-style, ascii, decoding, ambiguity

For an arbitrary precision integer class i wrote, I have a constructor that accepts a string containing the integer's value and an uint16_t to say what base the string is in.

```
integer("123", 10) -> 0x7b   -> 123   base 10
integer("ab", 256) -> 0x6162 -> 24930 base 10
```

Since my class can accept negative numbers as well, the constructor reads `-` as meaning the value is negative, a base 256 string (ASCII) with `-` as is first character messes things up. how should i change my code to make a `-` in front of an ASCII string not ambiguous? How would i differentiate between an input string that is `------` (positive 49672054713645 in base 10) and `------` (negative 194031463725 in base 10)?

Currently, i am considering all ASCII values as positive.

I hope to leave the constructor accepting only 2 arguments, but if the obvious: change/split/add the constructor to `integer(positive/negative, string, base)` is the only good idea, i may consider it

Comment: ASCII cannot be base 256 as it is a 7 bit encoding. 2^7 = 128 ASCII values. So you need an 8 bit extension of ASCII, which you should then specify.

Answer (score 1):

Most such string-to-integer routines I've seen only allow bases from 2 to 36, with base 36 using the character set `[0..9, a..z]`. If you do decide to support "base 256", I'd recommend that you only support positive values. (The caller can just negate the result if they happen to know it's negative.)

Another question you might want to ask yourself, incidentally, is whether you need to support all the intermediate bases between 2 and 256. There are some significant discontinuities you'll need to support; for instance, in base 16, both capital and lowercase letters are treated identically (which can't be the case for "base 256") and there's a gap between 9 (0x39) and A (0x41), and in all ordinary bases, '0' (0x30) is zero, not NUL (0x00).

Comment: i only have input bases of 2, 8, 10, 16, and 256. and yeah, i have a note saying to negate any base 256 inputs